# How to add elements from a generic type to a list <long> in JAVA?

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I'm new at posting questions here, but have been looking since yesterday for a solution for this and couldn't find. Would really appreciate the help.

I have two lines, at which I'm trying to put generic elements inside a list and get a type mismatch for sending Long elements to List.

```
List<Long> returnedPages = m_algo.getElement(Arrays.asList(pageIds));
List<Long> pagesNotInRam = new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> pageIdsToHandle = m_algo.putElement(pagesNotInRam, pagesNotInRam);
```

m_algo is defined

```
private IAlgoCache<Long, Long> m_algo;
```

and IAlgoCache works with generic types

```
public interface IAlgoCache <K, V> {
public V getElement(K key);
public V putElement(K key, V value);}
```

Can I make this work? Should I work in some sort of loop?

Comment: So what's the exactly problem?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: If your `m_algo` is defined as `IAlgoCache<Long, Long>` then `K` and `V` are supposed to represent `Long` value, not List of Long values. Maybe you wanted to define them as `IAlgoCache<List<Long>, List<Long>>` but something tells me this could be [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I thought about changing my replacement algorithm, but after over two hours of work, I've realized that this also will take days.. That's when I signed up here, thinking maybe there's some sort of solution to this issue which I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. For example

```
public V getElement(K key); // takes an object as an argument (Long in your case)
m_algo.getElement(Arrays.asList(pageIds));  // you pass a list of objects (I suppose longs)
```

And even if you fix that issue and pass a proper key later you are trying to  assign a Long object to a List. That's why it complains - assigning and object to a collection cannot be done because they are basically different types.

```
List<Long> returnedPages = m_algo.getElement( properKey ); // Problem
```

Try with:

```
 List<Long> returnedPages=new ArrayList();
 returnedPages.add(m_algo.getElement( properKey));
```

The problem with putElement is the same. You just need to distinguish between an object and an array or collection of objects. Even if they have the same type they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Sorry for not being 100% clear, like I've said, I'm new at asking questions here. so the error is of course the type mismatch "cannot convert from List<Long> to Long". And  "The method getElement(Long) in the type IAlgoCache<Long,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Long>)". And "The method putElement(Long, Long) in the type IAlgoCache<Long,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Long>, List<Long>)". Also didn't mention what's pageIds, it's defined as long[].

Comment: Yes I figured out the problems. That's why I told you to read a bit more about Longs and Lists and how to use them. For example if you want to add a Long to a List you do list.add(element) and not list=element. Etc.

Comment: @Rosh just for clarification, when you said pageIds is defined as `long[]`, did you actually mean `Long[]`? I suspect it's the latter, because if pageIds was `long[]` then `Arrays.asList(pageIds)` would have type `List<long[]>` instead of `List<Long>`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering and so quickly. So basically, a loop will do the trick? Like, first    List<Long> returnedPages=new ArrayList(); Then can go over pageIds[i] with a for loop and use    returnedPages.add(m_algo.getElement(pageIds[i])); ?

Comment: Yes that would do the trick ;) just keep in mind when you have a primitve long, an object Long or a collection List<Long>. Its like you cannot say Bowl<Apples> = Apple because bowl cannot be an aple, but you can do Bowl<Apple>.add(apple)

Comment: @Vaselin Davidov Again, thank you very much! sorry for taking a few days to reply again, I had to finish that project already. But your guidance really helped me get some things straight. Once you've mentioned the "add" command, I realized my whole approach here was wrong. I've went over the commands for collections, which I haven't used in a while, and that really pushed me through the project quickly. So again, thank you, and keep up the good work!

Comment: Also @DodgyCodeException, thanks for clearing up the difference between    List<long[]> and    List<Long> cause I wasn't actually sure which one is correct.